# IntelliJ and Maven trouble

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, plugins

I seem to allways run into problems with Maven in IntelliJ. Either things won't work, or things are red and the project still builds. The latter is better than the first, but I really don't like it.

Versions: IntelliJ 2022.1.1 Ultimate Ed., bild #IU-221.5591.52. Maven3.10.1

It's a working project this time. I've just upgraded it from Java 8 to 11.

It builds fine, and "mvn clean install" runs without issues.

However, in my pom.xml files I have these red lines:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M3</version>

<groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
   <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
<version>7.3.2</version>

....
```

Now, these were put here by those who owned the code before me, so I know little about what they're supposed to be/do. I've changed the versions, which didn't help.

No matter of refreshing of the maven packages, rebuild, reinstall seems to help.

The maven overview:

[image]

I've tried looking for the plugins in Plugins, but no match. There's a Maven Depencency Helper plugin, but installing that and refreshin, building and installing makes no difference.

Now, I don't think I NEED these, and the project seems to work fine without them. But I'd like to know for sure before I remove them.

Any tips? I've been looking at ever tip I can find, but they all seem to revolve around the things I've tried.

Comment: First question which version of IDEA IntelliJ do you use? Maven version?

Comment: IntelliJ 2022.1.1 Ultimate Ed., bild #IU-221.5591.52. Maven3.10.1 (not the newest, but that's not my decision since it's project dependant)

Comment: Are the `*` really there? They certainly shouldn't be.

Comment: Sorry - my bad. No, they're not really there :-)

Comment: Is it possible to check the issue with newer IDE version?